# Is there a relational database engine that will automatically map code values?

Tags: relational-database

I have a table with lots of redundant data.

I'd like to change some of the VARCHAR values to some sort of "AUTO_LOOKUP" data type, that automatically maintains and resolves values from a look-up table.

MySQL does this partially with the ENUM datatype, but it requires ahead-of-time definition of all known values. I would like the list of values to dynamically grow.

Does this exist?

Related questions:

- Similar concept, using a custom datatype in Derby: [User-defined types in Apache Derby as ENUM replacements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293986/user-defined-types-in-apache-derby-as-enum-replacements)
- Similar concept, but handling 100% in the client application (I want it handled in the database instead): [Ways to save enums in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229856/ways-to-save-enums-in-database?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called a foreign key, and it's supported by virtually all relational databases.

You define your set of varchars in a lookup table, with one row per value. Associated with the string is a more compact primary key, typically an auto-increment integer.

Then in your large table, just reference the entry in the lookup table by integer.